# Basic Interface Explanation

Tags: java, generics, interface

I feel like I should know this, but can't really explain it when asked. 
I have a method:

```
public <T extends IByteConverter<T>> int write(T obj) throws IOException {
    byte[] byteArray = obj.toByteArray();
    raFile.write(byteArray);
    //keeps track of size of what was written
    return byteArray.length;
}
```

and my interface:

```
interface IByteConverter<T> {
    public byte[] toByteArray();
    public T fromByteArray(byte[] byteArray);
}
```

When I call obj.toByteArray(), How does my program know what to do? No where in my class do I actually implement the code in IByteConverter, but the program works just as expected. Is there a simple way to explain what is going on?

Comment: By saying that it works, you actually mean it compiles right?

Comment: Yes, compliles and works as expected. Meaning it returns the object passed in, into a byte[].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's make the thing easier to understand with another example : you define an interface Fruit, which has a method `getColor()`. The contract of this method is that it returns a color.

Based on this contract, you define a class that takes an array of `Fruit`s, and counts the number of red ones.

You don't need any implementation for this method to *compile*, because you can be sure that the only thing that can be passed to this method is an array of objects, which are instances of a class that indeed implements the `Fruit` interface. In order for this method to be *run*, you'll need to define at least one class that implements the `Fruit` interface (like `Apple` for example), and to construct an array of objects of this class.

That's what polymorphism is all about: you can call a method of an object without knowing what its actual class is, provided it respects the contract of its interface.

Generics don't make this different. Since `obj` is of type `T`, and since `T` extends `IByteConverter`, you can call the `toByteArray()` method on `obj`.

Comment: Thanks so much, that makes more sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

This type of method `<T extends IByteConverter<T>>` gives possibility to know about internal methods of object `T`. This declaration obligates the caller to put paramaters that `extends` type `IByteConverter` so at least all methods from `IByteConverter` will be accessible inside this method.